# Debuggin with mocha, load globals

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, mocha.js, sinon

My goal is to debug one of my tests. I'm using Mocha as a base, and SinonJS for spies, stubs and mocks. For some unknown reason my stub of the ajax method has stopped working. It worked a week ago, now the requests are sent and the stub does not track the calls.

I have these lines inside the outermost `describe`

```
let sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
let ajaxStub = undefined;
```

and then this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    ajaxStub = sandbox.stub($, 'ajax');
});

afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore();

});
```

Anyway, my question is not what's wrong with this, I'm probably doing something extremely stupid elsewhere, and some debugging could probably solve it. My problem is with the debugging itself.

```
mocha --debug-brk --inspect ./test/mytest.js
```

This is what I run in command line to get the debugging session going.

My problem is to run the tests I'm currently using Gulp, with which I'm loading all my framework dependencies and all my globals - the libraries added this way include also `jQuery` and `sinon`

And of course, if I debug my tests using that command line, NodeJS does not load the required files in the environment, and at the first reference to sinon I get an exception.

I could create an html page in which I load required files and tests and run the test - then debug it manually with the browser inspector - but that's something that I would like to avoid. Is there anything more automated?

I'm not a NodeJS expert, I just roughly understand what it is and how it works, so I'm pretty confident there could be something I missed that can be of help :)

What I'm thinking about right now is a batch script to find the required files, but that's all I have.

Just an additional note: code base is really old and big, and I do not really have permission to refactor existing code into es6 modules.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I'm going to create a testDebugLoader.js script in which I will write which test I want to debug, and an array of paths to scripts I need to load.

Then loop trough the array, load each needed file, and call eval on the retrieved text.